Need help to create an AWS Lambda Layer for Python 3.12 and pyodbc
I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda Layer using Python 3.12 and pyodbc. I've seen a few different sites where they use an older version of Python and, when I try to translate to 3.12, it fails miserably.No matter how I build the zip file to upload, when I click the button to test my Lambda function, it tells me that pyodbc is not found.
In the end, my goal is to have a Lambda Layer using Python 3.12 that will allow me to communicate with an MS SQL Server database that is not an RDS.
Any help and insights would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried using docker but, once inside, the only download capability I seem to have is using dnf which doesn't have libodbc.so.2. Docker is also missing key functionality like dpkg, yum, and/or apt-get. I've tried pulling down a few already-packaged version (mostly Python 3.8) but the files for msodbcsql and unixODBC don't seem to match up. I have also tried building pymssql and that has fallen flat also.

Some of the advice I've seen say that init.py files are not needed by Lambda layers because the AWS Linux runtime loads paths, and I think that Lambda layers that I've created for Py3.11 and previous have gotten away without any. But for Py3.12, I have found that they are absolutely necessary for the Python packages in a custom Lambda layer. As an example of how on a Windows machine I get the necessary Python package for an AWS arm64 Lambda:
pip install --platform manylinux_2_17_aarch64 --only-binary=:all: --target="C:/aws/lambda_layers/py312/python"


I've created pre-built artifact zip files that support Python 3.9 to 3.12 for MSSQL Server connections using PyODBC, Microsoft ODBC drivers, and UNIXODBC
You can download and use them directly from my GitHub repo here.
Note: It currently supports x86_64 architecture
